# SQL Server query using temporary variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, cursor

I want to use this code by using temporary variable, please suggest.

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @salary INT

CREATE TABLE #Result1 (Name VARCHAR(50), Salary INT)

DECLARE zxcv CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        CASE
           WHEN LEN(Name) <= 5
              THEN CONCAT(Name, '_', LEN(Name))
              ELSE Name 
        END,
        Salary 
    FROM 
        Customers;

OPEN zxcv

FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv INTO @name, @salary;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Result1 (Name, Salary)
    VALUES (@name, @salary);

    FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv INTO @name, @salary;
END

CLOSE zxcv;
DEALLOCATE zxcv;

SELECT * FROM #Result1;
```

Comment: This works as coded and produces the result you supplied- what problem are you having?

Comment: i know that, code is producing the output result ... but i want to print the same result with temporary variable... can you plz help to do that same

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by this question or your last comment. You are going to have to come up with a way of describing what you mean by using temporary variable (BTW I do know what a temporary variable is) or possibly expand the question to describe what you are trying to achieve rather than your unacceptable attempt.

Comment: changes your temp table logic to use "temporary variable" let us know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID,
      IIF(LEN(Name)<=5,Name+'_'+CAST(LEN(Name) AS VARCHAR(10)) ,Name) As Name,
      Age
 FROM
(
SELECT 1 ID,'Abccd' Name, 23 Age UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ID,'Abccderdf' Name, 42 Age UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ID,'Abccd' Name, 64 Age 

)dt
```

Result

```
ID  Name        Age
-------------------
1   Abccd_5     23
2   Abccderdf   42
3   Abccd_5     64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(Name) <= 5 
          THEN Name + '_' + CAST(LEN(NAME) AS NVARCHAR(5))
          ELSE Name 
    END AS 'Name',
    Age
INTO 
    #Result1
FROM 
    Customers

SELECT * FROM #Result1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use Table variables instead of temp tables. Here is your edited code:-

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @salary INT

declare  @Result1 table(Name VARCHAR(50), Salary INT)

DECLARE zxcv CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        CASE
           WHEN LEN(Name) <= 5
              THEN CONCAT(Name, '_', LEN(Name))
              ELSE Name 
        END,
        Salary 
    FROM 
        Customers;

OPEN zxcv

FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv INTO @name, @salary;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Result1 (Name, Salary)
    VALUES (@name, @salary);

    FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv INTO @name, @salary;
END

CLOSE zxcv;
DEALLOCATE zxcv;

SELECT * FROM @Result1;
```